# datatables colreorder and then disable user reorder

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatable, datatables

I am ordering the column headers when the data table loads through the colReorder attribute.

```
var table = $("table#"+id+".data-table").DataTable({
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "pageLength": 25,
        "aaSorting": [],
        "colReorder": true,
        "colReorder": {
            "order": gon.table_ids[id].order
        },
        "responsive": true});
```

However, I don't want the user to have the ability to move the columns around. I just want the datatable to load my predefined column order and that is it. Currently, after datatables moves my columns around, the user is allowed to move the columns but I want it disabled. Anyway this is possible?

Comment: Do you see https://datatables.net/reference/option/colReorder.fixedColumnsLeft and https://datatables.net/reference/option/colReorder.fixedColumnsRight ?

Comment: wow i completely missed that. Thanks so much!

Comment: post you answer to mark as solved